# How to build an ionic application for android TV

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, ionic3, android-tv

I am trying to build an android application using ionic 3 for android TV

Is it possible if so can any on guide me how to achieve it.

On google surfing i got this one plugin but not much useful https://github.com/HughIsaacs2/Cordova-Android-TV-Plugin